# Rotate a certain portion of PDB file around a provided vector

Tags: biopython

Can I rotate a certain portion of PDB file around a given vector and angle (say ATOM-10, ATOM-100) using BioPython !
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I found a CCP4 command, 'pdbcur' and 'pdbset'. This helps me !